# Add ROW_NUMBER() function to SQL query

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select 
DISTINCT(b.org),
b.env,
b.proxy,
b."type",
b.name,
b.policytype,
b.disabled,
b."report refresh date",
b.rank,
first_value(LOWER(a."value")) 
over(partition by
b.org,
b.env,
b.proxy
order by b."report refresh date" desc
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as "value"


from 
(select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "report refresh date" DESC) as rank from infosec.apigee_policy_info_for_proxy) b


left join
(select * from api.apigee_product
where attribute = 'tui-api-domain') a

on a.org = b.org 
and a.env = b.env
and a.proxy = b.proxy

where b.rank <=60

group by b.org,
b.env,
b.proxy,
b."type",
b.name,
b.policytype,
b.disabled,
b."report refresh date",
b.rank,
a."value"
```

and need to add a function in the end of the above query that calculates the row number.
For that I have the following query:

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by "report refresh date" ASC) as rowid
```

I'm having problems on where to put it, in the first query showned.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` at the same time. Your problem is also not clear, do you encounter an error using `ROW_NUMBER()`? If you don't use any aggregation, why `GROUP BY`? If you try to prevent duplications, try using `PARTITION BY` in your `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Then, I think you can put it anywhere in `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ - and it "belongs" to the SELECT. `SELECT DISTINCT` returns distinct _rows_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select DISTINCT b.org, b.env, ...` - to make code clearer!

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify this query as :

```
select distinct b.org, b.env, b.proxy, b.type,b.name,
       b.policytype, b.disabled, b."report refresh date", b.rank,
       first_value(LOWER(a."value")) 
             over(partition by b.org, b.env, b.proxy order by b."report refresh date" desc                      
                    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as "value",
       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by "report refresh date" ASC) as rowid
from (select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "report refresh date" DESC) as rank 
      from infosec.apigee_policy_info_for_proxy
     ) b left join 
       api.apigee_product a
       on a.org = b.org and 
          a.env = b.env and
          a.proxy = b.proxy and
          a.attribute = 'tui-api-domain'
where b.rank <= 60;
```

Note : `DISTINCT`  is not function so, removed `()`. Use `LEFT JOIN` directly instead of subquery.